# How to clear only date or only time when the input type date and input type time uses same ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, time, ionic-framework

In ionic app and using angularjs.

I have a form and in that it displays date and time separately for a same data-ng-model as:

```
<input type="date" id ="actualVisitDate" data-ng-model="actualVisitDate" required>
<input type="time" id ="actualVisitTime" data-ng-model="actualVisitDate" required>
```

When it is running on device, if I want to clear a date, then it also removes time also and vice versa. So how do I restrict that it only clears the date field or time field.
Here is the screenshot :

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: you need to maintain different model names....can you show your js that rendering date and time to the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reference both the input tag with same name "actualVisitDate" due to this when you clear one other will also clear or vice versa.

you should use different references  name for both the tag.